# How should we tag flash games?

Tags: discussion, tags

Flash games aren't overly common, but there doesn't seem to be much of a consensus on how to tag them. Most of them were tagged with the game's name and [flash](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash), but as most flash games don't have too much depth, the game's tag degrades, and it's left with just the [flash](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash) tag. An exception is [Gemcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=gemcraft), which wasn't tagged with flash anyway.

How should we tag these? Just [flash](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash)? Just the game name? Both?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say both tags. Every game tag should be given a chance.

Comment: Considering our stance on tagging other games with platforms only if they're about a specific version or about the platform itself, shouldn't we technically leave the flash tag out if that particular version of the game is exclusive to being a flash game? Otherwise, we're going to have people trying to tag questions with other platform tags again when it's unnecessary.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes: Personally, I like the flash tag. It implies that the game is free an easily accessible, I can just go play it right now and try to figure out the answer, which I wouldn't do with say a PS3 game.

Answer (score 1):

You should really tag it with both, but if the Flash game is not popular or known on a wide scale, just tag with Flash. That's just my opinion, though.

Answer (score -1):

The tag does look like a bastard child of an hypotetical (bad) [games-no-one-else-but-me-plays-qq](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games-no-one-else-but-me-plays-qq) tag, even [once you remove the cruft.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bflash%5D%20-%5Bidentify-this-game%5D%20closed:0)

The correct course of action probably is removing [flash](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash) and adding the game tag instead... but who knows how long those will last. :-/

Comment: A third of those were asked by me.  Nice.